# Fixed columns of the same size positioned vertically

Tags: html, css

I have 100% width and height background image as a home page, and 100% wide subpages below it with different height.

Each of those subpages has two columns - one to the left is 100% height fixed image, and one to the right is the content. Scrolling the content does not move the image until I begin moving to another subpage below it.

I hope you do understand what I mean, it's pretty common web design as far as I know.

---

The problem is that I can't get it working - fixed column is always at the top of the whole website, I can't position them one below another.

How could I do this?

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-8" style="background-color: #a9a8a8; min-height: 100%;">Content goes here...</div>
     <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1" style="position: relative;">
           <div class="col-xs-3" style="position: fixed; top: 0; height: 100%;">
                 <img src="/assets/image/fixedImage.png">
           </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

This is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eL12rydd/
And this is the effect I want to obtain more or less (scroll down): http://ostro.tv

Comment: Could you create a fiddle with your problem?

Comment: There are some closing DIVs missing in your code. Please try again with syntactically correct code and edit your post. It wold be nice if you would use an indent of only 2 spaces to make it better readable.

Comment: Sure, I edited the question.